# wire on the floor. What is it likely was used for?

Tags: electrical

I bought a rehab house.
This is what I think was a laundry room because of the drier hookup.
What is this wire laying on the floor? What was it used for?

my current thoughts:

a) There are many baseboard heaters in the house - could there have been a baseboard heating panel there?
b) I cannot find a water heater in the house... it was taken. Could that have been a water heater connection?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In my area you only see wire ran along the floor for dish washers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

110v for washer, 220 v (the black outlet) for electric dryer, vent for dryer exhaust, drainpipe for washer exhaust., Presumably there are hot and cold water supply pipes for the washer too, unless they were looted for the copper... in which case I'd bet you'll have to redo most of the wiring and plumbing, and gods only know what problems were simply neglected... I hope you got a really good deal on this place.

But, yeah, the wire on the floor looks most likely to have been for something built-in such as electric baseboard heat. On the other hand, it could have been for a kickplate or surface-box outlet. Really no way to know unless you can trace it to a labelled breaker.

Comment: I got a good deal. 50k for a house in CT, no mortgage or any bills other then electrical - I'm very happy with it so far. and you were absoltely right -  baseboard heater was there.

Comment: Ok, at that price even if you remove the house an build something new you probably come out ahead. Might even be cheaper to do that, modulo just enough that it retains all its grandfathered zoning.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there is a drain for the washing machine coming out of the wall, and the drier vent is right next to it, so I think it is more likely that it went to a washing machine. Since there is no plug on the wire, it may have been hardwired.

Try to trace the wire back to the panel to see if anyone labeled it. Also, make sure that the circuit is dead before touching it.

Comment: but right above it - there is a black hookup for the washer and right next to it - blue hookup for a drier it seems? so that floor wire seems to be an extra one?

Comment: Besides the washer being there, it is really hard to tell what was there before. Regardless of what the original purpose was, it is a really bad idea to try to use any of the original wiring. The condition of it frankly, is pretty scary. It looks like someone came in and stole all the copper pipes, and the place was abandoned for some time.

Comment: Remove all the moldy drywall, and any other drywall that's in the way, and replace ALL the wires. Only sensible approach when it's got into this shape. At the absolute minimum, you need to expose & inspect any wires you think you might re-use - they have no doubt been yanked on by copper thieves, and may be damaged in hidden places.